# Unable to set cell values in Python Pandas SparseDataFrame

Tags: pandas, sparse-matrix

I'm having a hard time getting cell values to stick in a SparseDataFrame when updating by index/column.  I've tried setting cell values using df.at, df.ix, df.loc and the dataframe remains empty.

```
df = pd.SparseDataFrame(np.zeros((10,10)), default_fill_value=0)
df.at[1,1] = 1
df.ix[2,2] = 1
df.loc[3,3] = 1

df
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
6  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
7  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
8  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
9  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Any one of these options work fine on a standard dataframe.

The one option I've found that works is

```
df = df.set_values(1, 1, 1)
```

But this is terribly slow for a large matrix.

[edit] I did see a 4 year old answer that suggested the below, but it suggests that more direct methods were in the works. I also haven't tested speed on this, but it seems like converting whole slides of the matrix to dense and back would be much slower than directly updating a row,col, val entry as you can with scipy sparse matrices.

```
df = pd.SparseDataFrame(columns=np.arange(250000), index=np.arange(250000))
s = df[2000].to_dense()
s[1000] = 1
df[2000] = s

In [11]: df.ix[1000,2000]
Out[11]: 1.0
```

Comment: in pandas `0.20.3` it is a bit different - `at` does not work, `ix, loc, set_values` return errors. But last `4 years` solution works nice

Comment: Thanks for replying. The 4 year old answer is working, but it appears to be orders of magnitude slower than inserting values into a scipy sparse matrix.  Perhaps the right approach is to build the sparse matrices first and then convert to pandas later.

Comment: Yes, I think it is good idea.